# Using Plot3D for finding trend clearly

Tags: plotting, functions

I have a function of two positive variables $t$ and $C$ with $t$ and $C$ in a specific range as below. $0 < C < 10^{-5}$ and $0< t <4.54 \times 10^{-6}$. 
I want to see which variable of $C$ where the value of the function doesn't depend much on the variable $t$. So I used `Plot3D[]` function. However, from the plot I can vaguely see the trend. Is there a way to see it more clearly in *Mathematica*?

Function:

```
(0.0002607680962081059*(-1 + E^((63.9137490706142*Sqrt[6.799999999999999*^-6 - 144*C]*t)/C)))/(E^((12254.901960784315*(6.799999999999999*^-6 + 0.002607680962081059*Sqrt[6.799999999999999*^-6 - 144*C])*t)/C)*Sqrt[6.799999999999999*^-6 - 144*C])
```

Plot:

```
Plot3D[(0.0002607680962081059` E^(-((12254.901960784315` (6.799999999999999`*^-6+0.002607680962081059` Sqrt[6.799999999999999`*^-6-144 C]) t)/C)) (-1+E^((63.9137490706142` Sqrt[6.799999999999999`*^-6-144 C] t)/C)))/Sqrt[6.799999999999999`*^-6-144 C],{C,0,10^-5},{t,0,4.54 10^-6},AxesLabel->{C,t,VL}, PlotRange-> All,Mesh-> None,Background->Black,AxesStyle->White,Boxed->False]
```

Comment: I'd suggest reducing the `C` range to `{C, 0, 10^-6}` to zoom in on a more interesting region of your plot; I would also suggest using `DensityPlot` or `ContourPlot` instead of `Plot3D` to capture some features of your 3D graph as a 2D projection, which may be more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to see which variable of C where the value of the function doesn't depend much on the variable t

For this, I would plot the derivative of the function with respect to `t`, in those regions where it is close to 0, then the dependence on `t` is weakest.

```
f[C_, t_] := (0.0002607680962081059` E^(-((12254.901960784315` \
(6.799999999999999`*^-6 + 
              0.002607680962081059` Sqrt[
                6.799999999999999`*^-6 - 144 C]) t)/C)) (-1 + 
       E^((63.9137490706142` Sqrt[6.799999999999999`*^-6 - 144 C] t)/
          C)))/Sqrt[6.799999999999999`*^-6 - 144 C];
With[
 {dfdt = D[f[C, t], t]},
 Plot3D[{dfdt, 0}, {C, 0, 10^-5}, {t, 0, 4.54 10^-6}, 
  PlotRange -> {-10^4, 10^4}, AxesLabel -> {C, t, VL}, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
 ]
```

[image]

As you can see, nowhere in this range is the derivative with respect to `t` equal to zero, so the function always has some dependence on `t`.  But that dependence is strongest between `C=0` and `C=5*10^(-6)`.

You can view the derivative using a regular `Plot` as well,

```
With[
 {dfdt = D[f[C, t], t], cvalues = Range[2 10^-6, 10^-5, 2.0 10^-6]},
 Plot[Evaluate[
   dfdt /. C -> # & /@ cvalues
   ], {t, 0, 4.54 10^-6}, 
  PlotLegends -> (Row[{"C = ", #}] & /@ cvalues)]]
```

[image]

Comment: Well, extremely impressive! Thank you very much.